# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having a problem trying to run an Android app and getting the following error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse
```

when I try to run the app.

Comment: Post code and your logcat.

Comment: Are you using any external jar file?

Answer (score 4):

Check the answer here  : [NoClassDefFound solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845778/noclassdefexception-starting-activity-from-another-package/21845985#21845985)

You need to make few changes in your project through Eclipse project/properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add Parse jar to your libs folder and add it to the buildpath

Answer (score 0):

Even i was facing this same error, and solved by changing my minSdkVersion  to lesser (previously it was 11 i changed to 8)